# Is there a way to iterate using .join?

Tags: python, join, text-processing

I am trying to fix this code that I found from this website https://projectgurukul.org/spam-filtering-machine-learning/ but its somewhat broken. The error is 'float' object is not iterable.

```
lstem = LancasterStemmer()
def mess(messages):
  message_x = []
  for me_x in messages:
    #filter out other datas except alphabets
    me_x=''.join(filter(lambda mes:(mes.isalpha() or mes==" ") ,me_x)) # error on this line
    #tokenize or split the messages into respective words
    words = word_tokenize(me_x)
    #stem the words to their root words
    message_x+=[' '.join([lstem.stem(word) for word in words])]
  return message_x
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File D:\spam-filtering-ml-code\spamdetector.py:31 in <module>
    message_x = mess(message_X)

  File D:\spam-filtering-ml-code\spamdetector.py:24 in mess
    me_x=''.join(filter(lambda mes:(mes.isalpha() or mes==" ") ,me_x))

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You should check that `me_x` is actually `str`. For `str` I would expect this to work.

Comment: I'm not sure why is not working.

Comment: Print the contents of the `messages` argument at the beginning of the `mess` function. High chances the list contains a float as one of its' elements.